# How to embed Instagram Stories in iframe placeholder

Tags: api, iframe, instagram, embed

I'm trying to find a way to integrate Instagram Stories into iframe placeholder. I'm able to do it on the posts by simply adding embed at the end of the link (https://www.instagram.com/p/Cc0gdYSFqG_/embed/) but I can't replicate the same for the stories.

Can anyone guide me how shall I do it?

thanks